# Ruby pretty print isn't very pretty

Tags: ruby

When I use Ruby's built in Pretty Print (pp), the result comes back on a single line. For example, this is what I see:

```
require 'pp'

pp [1, 2, 3]
# [1, 2, 3]

pp({ a: 'b', c: 'd', e: 'f' })
# {:a=>"b", :c=>"d", :e=>"f"}
```

From reading online, my understanding was that it should actually output something like:

```
pp [1, 2, 3]
# [
#   1,
#   2,
#   3
# ]

pp({ a: 'b', c: 'd', e: 'f' })
# {
#   :a => "b",
#   :c => "d",
#   :e => "f"
# }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered using awesome_print instead? I use 2.1.2 and run into the same problem, but no problem with awesome_print...

Comment: You are not missing anything. It is a valid opinion. However, your question is too trivial to be asked as a question here.

Comment: Or, if you thought that the well formatted outputs you often see are all result of `pp` output, then you are wrong. Where did you get that idea? Your question might have made more sense if you had asked **how** to output those forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small Array (or Hash), the print is made on one single line, because it's (arguably) understandable at the first glimpse.

```
require 'pp'

ary = [1, 2, 3]
aaaaarrraaay = (1..100).to_a

pp ary
#> [1, 2, 3]
pp aaaaarrraaay
#> [1,
#>  2,
#>  3,
#>  4,
#>  5,
#>  ...
#>  100]
```

This depends wether or not your printed output is above 79 chars. (see [the code that does it](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/pp.rb#L97-L103))

However you can change that if your using `PP.pp` instead of `pp`

```
def my_pp(anything)
    PP.pp(anything, out = $>, width = 0)
end

my_pp [1, 2, 3]
#> [1,
#>  2,
#>  3]
```